# How can I call methods from a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I print this method from the class?

I'm new to Ruby so I'm not sure who to print this. I essentially need to enter a number into this method and print.

Similar to a JS function, I know I must use `puts`, but that's pretty much about it.

```
class Celcius
  def initialize(temperature)
    @temperature = temperature
  end

  def fahrenheit
    (@temperature * 1.8 + 32).round
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@temperature} degrees C"
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post code as **plain text** in the body of your question. Adding it as an image makes it very difficult for people to adapt your code to an answer, you can't copy-paste it, and it's hostile to those dependent on screen-readers.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you need to print something:

```
temp = Celcius.new(120)

puts temp.to_s
```

Now `puts` likes to convert things to string, and `to_s` is the default way of doing this, so this should work:

```
puts temp
```